# Два div'a в один список

Tags: css3, html, css

Всем привет!
Есть такой код.
http://jsfiddle.net/KGkrt/
Как сделать так, чтобы они были списком?! Делал сам, не получилось :(
Сделал только как на ссылке. Помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KGkrt/1/
И, пожалуйста, почитайте про форматирование кода.

Comment: Вроде список - это обычно сверху вниз

Comment: не обязательно, но если с такой сторноы то вот http://jsfiddle.net/KGkrt/3/

Comment: А можно слева направо?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arturpanteleev/KGkrt/5/ только растяните окошко

Answer (score 0):

[Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/KGkrt/2/)